# GWT Cloner needed to deep clone an object in memory

Tags: java, gwt, clone

I need to deep clone an object in GWT. In server side there are utilities such: http://code.google.com/p/cloning/ which use reflection thus are not available in GWT.

I was thinking maybe a solution is the ObjectStreamWriter.

Do you know an automatic cloning better solution?

Comment: I'd be surprised if one existed.  (Cloning is sort of _generally_ broken -- see e.g. Effective Java item 11 -- and you're better off writing copy constructors and the like.)

Comment: Agree but I just want a memcpy like; call it clone, call it copy contructor. The less painful way :D

Comment: There isn't one.  (The default `clone` implementation is sort of like that, but...just doing a dumb `memcpy` is an excellent way to break many Java objects, which is part of why `clone` is generally considered broken.)  You're almost certainly going to have to do things the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of using GWT Serialization to clone an object in the front-end because this kind of serialization is not symmetric.

If you pay attention to the GWT RPC requests and responses you will see that in the request the separator is the "|" and in the response the separator is the ",". Obviously this is not the only difference and replacing the separator will not help.

This means that an object serialized in javascript will only be deserialized in the server and an object serialized in the server will only be deserialized in javascript.

Comment: For the backend I have managed to create a pair of custom SerializationStreamWriter and SerializationStreamReader so I could serialize and deserialize to send it to disk. I had to do this because my class was not Java serializable (it extends GXT2s RpcMap which has a transient field).
In the front-end I think it is possible to create a generator like this:

    public interface Cloner<E> {
        public E clone(E obj);
    };
    public interface MyBeanCloner extends Cloner<MyBean> {}
    private MyBeanCloner myBeanCloner = GWT.create(MyBeanCloner.class);